# How to supply multi line command to subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, dtrace

I need to be able to run a multi line dtrace script via python subprocess.Popen, and tried this... have the following code snippet in python but this does not work, what is the correct approach for handling such templates?

```
    cmd = "/usr/sbin/dtrace -n '
    #pragma D option quiet
    profile:::profile-1001hz
    /arg0/
    {
            \@pc[arg0] = count();
    }
    dtrace:::END
    {
            printa("%a %\@d\\n", \@pc);
    }'"

    def execute_hotkernel():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    (output, error) = proc.communicate()
    print output
```

Using the quotes does not help enclose the multi line command into `cmd`. Get the following error when attempted to run `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: Answer edited. Actually I changed it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're a couple things happening here. The `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` is because you've tried to create a multi-line string with just a double-quote, which isn't legal in python. You can do it with a triple double-quote:

```
cmd = """/usr/sbin/dtrace -n '
#pragma D option quiet
...
"""
```

The second problem you'll have is that by default, `subprocess.Popen` wants an array of strings, not a space-separated shell command. You can pass `Popen` a `shell=True` argument to make it accept a string like you have here. Alternatively, break the command into pieces and just put the dtrace script in your multi-line string:

```
dtrace_script = """#pragma D option quiet
profile:::profile-1001hz
/arg0/
{
        \@pc[arg0] = count();
}
dtrace:::END
{
        printa("%a %\@d\\n", \@pc);
}
"""
...
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/sbin/dtrace', '-n', dtrace_script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that is neat, just one thing, the newline embedded in that string literal i.e the newline in the line `print("%a %\@d\\n", \@pc);` is causing the following error to be thrown `newline encountered in string literal`

Comment: I guess I had the \\n left out, that helps overcome the problem mentioned in previous comment. Just use `\\n`

Answer (score 2):

```
arg3 = '''
#pragma D option quiet
profile:::profile-1001hz
/arg0/
{
        \@pc[arg0] = count();
}
dtrace:::END
{
        printa("%a %\@d\\n", \@pc);
}
'''
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/sbin/dtrace', '-n', arg3], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
```

The first argument to `Popen` is a list of arguments, unless `shell=True` and that is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

That error is because you have to use triple `"` for multiline string literal.

```
 s = """#pragma D option quiet
    profile:::profile-1001hz
    /arg0/
    {
            \@pc[arg0] = count();
    }
    dtrace:::END
    {
            printa("%a %\@d\\n", \@pc);
    }"""
```

But I recommend you to create a file with the script, and then run it using Popen.

```
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/sbin/dtrace', 'script_you_have_just_created.td'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Anyway if the script don't change, there is no need to keep it in a variable in your code.